Lazy load always load largest images
I have implemented lazy load with this code:
<script>
(function(w, d) {
    var b = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var s = d.createElement("script");
    var v = !("IntersectionObserver" in w) ? "8.17.0" : "10.20.1";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-lazyload/" + v + "/lazyload.min.js";
    w.lazyLoadOptions = {
        elements_selector: '.lazy',
        threshold: 250
    };
    b.appendChild(s);
}(window, document));

Image:
<img class="mimg lazy" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEHAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="https://example.com/photos/galeries/11992/11992_3.jpg" data-srcset="https://example.com/photos/galeries/11992/11992_3.jpg 650w, https://example.com/photos/galeries/11992/11992_xxl_3.jpg 1600w" sizes="(max-width: 992px) 650px, (min-width: 993px) 1600px, 650px" width="650" height="433" alt="Alt text" />

The question is that it is always loading the largest image xxl.
I don't know why it doesn't load the little image for example in mobile devices.
Thank you

How can you tell? The point of lazy loading is that it loads the full image when it scrolls into view, so you won't see the small image unless it takes a while to load the large image.

In developers console I see the image that is loading and always is the xxl even if the screen size is less than 650px. It should load one image or another depending on the screen size.

Finally I could fix it including the img between picture and using sources with the different sizes of screens and images, this is the final code for the image.
I followed the instructions from here: https://github.com/dverbovyi/lazyload on Responsive images - picture tag
<picture><source media="(max-width: 992px)" data-srcset="https://example.com/photos/galeries/11992/11992_3.jpg"><source media="(min-width: 993px)" data-srcset="https://example.com/photos/galeries/11992/11992_xxl_3.jpg"><img class="mimg lazy" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEHAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="https://example.com/photos/galeries/11992/11992_xxl_3.jpg" width="650" height="433" alt="Alt text"></picture>


Please explain in more detail, showing how you changed the code.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
